# Problem placing numbers after Vedic accents in Tamil

Tags: fontspec, polyglossia

I am having a problem placing a number after a vedic accent in Tamil. The minimum map file is

```
**********************************************************************
LHSName "tamv"
RHSName "UNICODE"
LHSDescription "Tamil With Numbered Consonants for Vedic Accents"
Version "1.0

Define g U+0067
Define u U+0075
Define l U+006C
Define a U+0061
Define m U+006D
Define umatra   U+0BC1
Define virama   U+0BCD
Define zwnj U+200C
Define zwj  U+200D

Define ga   U+0B95
Define ma   U+0BAE
Define la   U+0BB2

Define three   U+2083

Define unsc    U+005F
Define anudatta U+0952

pass(Unicode)
g u > ga umatra three
l a > la
m > ma virama
g u unsc > ga umatra anudatta three
***********************************************************************
```

My tex file is

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newcommand{\tamvfont}{Noto Sans Tamil SemiCondensed} 

\newcommand{\tamv}[1][1.20]{
    \catcode`\^=12
    \catcode`\~=12
    \catcode`\_=12
    \fontspec[WordSpace=1.50,Script=Tamil,Mapping=tamv,Scale=#1]{\tamvfont}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
{\tamv gulam\\
gu_lam}
\end{document}
```

My output is
[image]

There are two words. The two words are exactly the same except that the second word has a Vedic Accent below the first letter. I want to get rid of the circle and make the 3 as shown in the first word.

Comment: Could you please format your code as code in the future? It'd be much easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

It’s an issue with your font.  You can try to see if there’s another that supports this combination, but one workaround is to borrow the subscript 3 from Noto Sans.  Here’s an example (of an input method you would not actually use, but which makes it very clear what the codepoints are):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}

\setmainfont{Noto Sans Tamil}[
  Script=Tamil,
  Renderer=HarfBuzz]
\newfontfamily\scriptsfont{Noto Sans}

\newcommand\subthree{{\scriptsfont\symbol{"2083}}}
\newunicodechar{₃}{\subthree}

\setdefaultlanguage{tamil}

\begin{document}
^^^^0b85^^^^0bc1^^^^2083^^^^0bb2^^^^0bae

^^^^0b85^^^^0bc1^^^^0952{\subthree}^^^^0bb2^^^^0bae

அு₃லம

அு॒₃லம
\end{document}
```

[image: Noto Sans Tamil sample]